# Power Series, Taylor/Maclaurin and n-th derivative

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

> a) Find the convergence radius of the power series $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^∞\frac{(n+1)^{n^2}}{3^nn^{n^2}}x^n $$
>
> b)Find all the $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for which the power series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^∞\frac{(x+1)^n}{\sqrt{4^nn}}$ converge.
>
> c)Using the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$, find the power series of $g(x)=e^{5x^2}$ with center $x_0=0$. Also for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ find a formula for $g^{(n)}(0)$.

**My work so far:**

a) I found $R=\frac{3}{e}$ with $R={(\limsup_{n\rightarrow∞}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|})}^{-1}$.

b) From the ratio test and $n\rightarrow ∞$ we get $|(x+1)\frac{1}{2}|$. So the power series converge for $|(x+1)\frac{1}{2}|<1$. Thus $-3<x<1$ is the interval of convergence of the power series.

c) The power series of $g(x)$ using the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x$ is  ${\sum_\limits{n=0}^ ∞}\frac{5^n}{n!}x^{2n}$

Is my work correct so far?
I don't know what to do for the n-th derivative of $g(x)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Maclaurin series for $f$ is:
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^nf(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\right|_{x=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
I think this will be enough for you to finish the excercise c.

So, the first few terms of the Maclaurin series are:
$$g^{(0)}(0)\frac{x^0}{0!}+g^{(1)}(0)\frac{x^1}{1!}+g^{(2)}(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots$$
$$g^{(0)}(0)+g^{(1)}(0)x+g^{(2)}(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots$$
While your function is:
$$5^0\frac{x^{2*0}}{0!}+5^1\frac{x^{2*1}}{1!}+5^2\frac{x^{2*2}}{2!}+\dots$$
$$1+5x^2+\frac{25}{2}x^4+\dots$$

Comment: If i get this right ${\sum_{n=0}^ ∞}\frac{5^n}{n!}x^{2n}={\sum_{n=0}^∞}\frac{\text{d}^nf(x)}{\text{d}x^n}|_{x=0}\frac{x^n}{n}$, thus $f^{(n)}(0)=5^nx^n$ ???

Comment: Almost! Why don't you try to write out the first few terms of both sums?

Comment: I edited the convergence radius i forgot to write $(x+1)\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm gonna remove that from my answer then. And also, the left side ($f^{(n)}(0)$) is not a function of $x$, but the right side ($5^n x^n$) is, and that's a problem. I think you will notice the pattern by writing out the terms, maybe up to $n=2$.

Comment: I get the same result $f^{(n)}(x)=5^nx^n$. i'm sorry if it's obvious and i don't get it.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now, try to compare the coefficients of $x^n$, they should be the same. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: A little bit of hint: What is the coefficient of $x$, for example? From the Maclaurin series, it should be $g'(0)$, but from your function, it's $0$.

Comment: I think i got it. $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0, f''(0)=25, f'''(0)=0, f^{(4)}=300,...$. So for odd powers its zero and for even is multiple of 5?

Comment: Exactly! For odd $n$, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, and for even $n$, $f^{(n)}(0)=5^{n/2}$. Sorry, I can't help in the other excercises.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I was trying to lead you to the solution instead of just telling it to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74175/discussion-between-argiriskar-and-botond).

Answer (score 0):

Finding the n-th derivative of $g$ is easy, since you have already found the Maclaurin expansion:

- Since $g$ is an even function, $g^{(n)}(0)=0$, if $n$ is odd.
- From the Maclaurin expansion, if $n$ is even:

  - $
    \begin{align*}
     g(x)
    =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
    =\sum_{v=0}^\infty \frac{5^v}{v!}x^{2v}\Rightarrow
    x^n=x^{2v}\Rightarrow
    n=2v
    \end{align*}
    $
  - $
    \begin{align*}
    g(x)
    =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
    =\sum_{v=0}^\infty\frac{5^v}{v!}x^{2v}\Rightarrow
    \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{5^v}{v!}\Rightarrow
    g^{(n)}(0)
    =\frac{5^vn!}{v!}
    =\frac{\sqrt{5^n}n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}
    \end{align*}
    $

A piecewise definition of the n-th derivative of $g$ would be:
$$
g^{(n)}(0)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt{5^n}n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}&n \to even\\ 0&n \to odd\end{cases}
$$